# Import-CSV separated by ; instead of , PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm using a CSV to store some information which I want to use in Powershell. To make the CSV more "readeable" I decided to put every piece of information into a separate field. If I use `import-csv` in powershell, the return is like this:

```
Test1;Test2;Test3
-----------------
Val1;Val2;Val3
```

PowerShell can't handle the `;` - so I was asking myself if there is any way to import the CSV as it is now, but replace every ";" with a "," so PowerShell will use it as

```
Test1  Test2  Test3
-----  -----  -----
Val1   Val2   Val3
```

I tried it like this

```
$test = (import-csv test.csv).Replace(";",",")
```

but it doesn't work

Does anyone have a solution? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Import-CSV` can handle the `;` delimiter just fine - use the `-delimiter ';'` -parameter.